# why recursion function returns "NaN" here

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I have to find the sum of the absolute difference between consecutive elements of the array. But sumAbsArr function returns nun

```js
var arr = [1, 5, 2];
var n = 3;
var cur = 0;

console.log(sumAbsArr(arr, n, cur))

function sumAbsArr(arr, n, cur) {
  if (n == cur) {
    return 0
  }
  var abs = Math.abs(arr[cur] - arr[cur + 1])
  var ans = abs + sumAbsArr(arr, n, cur + 1)
  return ans
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `arr[cur + 1]` exists? If you’re not sure, learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs). [Rubber Duck Debug](//rubberduckdebugging.com/) your code. Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) to your advantage — hint: `console.log({ cur, plus1: arr[cur + 1] })`.

Comment: I think it's `NaN` and not `NUN`, which would be quite a good deal different

Comment: You don't have to use an extra variable `n` for the length of an array that you are already passing into the function. You could just use `arr.length` to get the same value. Or `arr.length - 1` might have been even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are wrong at placing the condition. Look at arr[cur+1] (at line 11), when  cur = 3 the cur+1 is out of range (arr index is start at 0 and end at arr.length-1 which is 2). So to prevent arr[cur+1] have NaN value, you have to change the condition

```js
var arr = [1, 5, 2];
var n = 3;
var cur = 0;

console.log(sumAbsArr(arr, n, cur))

function sumAbsArr(arr, n, cur) {
  // change the condition to stay within the range
  if (cur == n-1) { 
    return 0
  }
  var abs = Math.abs(arr[cur] - arr[cur + 1])
  var ans = abs + sumAbsArr(arr, n, cur+1)
  return ans
}
```